# How to generate a tabulated and limited by ';' txt file (or csv) with a defined numer of characters for each column of a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working with a dataframe and I need to generate a txt file with a defined number of characters for each column

I was given the required format for the txt file and the specifications include number of characters for each column, separated by ';'

I've tried with this code:

```
np.savetxt(filename, df, fmt='%s', delimiter='\t;')
```

And I get this txt file:

```
2   ;000100000001X  ;20190626   ;Example Name   ;Example Adress
2   ;000100000002X  ;20190626   ;Example Name   ;Example Adress
2   ;000100000003X  ;20190626   ;Example Longer Name    ;Example Adress
2   ;000000010TR    ;20190626   ;Example Longer Name    ;Example Adress
2   ;000000011TR    ;20190626   ;Example Name   ;Example Adress
```

But this output is needed:

```
2;000100000001X;20190626;Example Name        ;Example Adress
2;000100000002X;20190626;Example Name        ;Example Adress
2;000100000003X;20190626;Example Longer Name ;Example Adress
2;000000010TR  ;20190626;Example Longer Name ;Example Adress
2;000000011TR  ;20190626;Example Name        ;Example Adress
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would do is loop over the information that you have (i.e. rows in an array), and write a formatted string to a file for each iteration:

```
a= 'string'
b= 'test'

with open('textfile.txt', 'a') as file:
    for row in array:
       file.write('{:>10}'.format(a)+';'+'{:>10}'.format(b)+'\n')
```

You'll have to tailor the '{:>10}' part for your particular file. For details on formatting strings for example https://pyformat.info/